# 1つのQRコードでWiFi接続+特定のページ表示を可能としているアプリケーションの存在

Tags: qr-code

QRコードをかざすと指定のSSIDに接続し、かつ指定のURLにアクセスする仕組みを作りたいと考えております。
それぞれ個別のQRコードを作成することはできますが、2つの処理を行うようなQRコード作成は可能でしょうか。

QRコードを作成するとき、テキストとして以下を指定しましたが、WiFi接続のみでした。

> WIFI:T:WPA;S:mynetwork;P:mypasscode;;
>   http://test.html

ご教授よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 4):

QRコードは単にデータをバーコード化したものであり、それ自身にそうした機能や仕組みはありません。

処理を行っているのはアプリケーションであり、1つのQRコードで「WiFi接続+特定のページ表示」を可能としているアプリケーションが存在するかどうかが重要です。

そうしたアプリケーションを探すか、要望を出して作ってもらうか、自分で作るかする必要があります。

探す場合は、QRコードの作り方について質問するのではなく、「**1つのQRコードでWiFi接続+特定のページ表示を可能としているアプリケーションの存在**」について質問してください。
(**注:** 書いておいてナンですが、それだけだとオフトピックとされる可能性があります。ヘルプ [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
を参考に質問内容は工夫してください）
そうしたアプリケーションが存在するならば、そのアプリケーションの仕様に従ってQRコードを作成すれば良いでしょう。

作る場合は、使いやすい仕様を独自に考えて実装する必要があります。
その場合QRコードの内容・作り方は、ある程度自由に自分で組み立てることが出来ます。

あるいは、既に存在する個々のアプリケーションを利用して、組み合わせた処理を1回で行っているように見せる、という方法も考えられます。

参考サイト・記事
[iPhone で QR コードからの Wi-Fi 接続が意外と知られていなかったので補足](https://note.mu/jp_pancake/n/n2c5d8d8aa868)

> QR コードを読み取るだけで Wi-Fi にサッと接続できるので便利ですよ。
>
> このほか Apple の公式ビデオ では QR コードと Universal Links でシームレスにアプリを起動する方法を紹介しています。

[Universal Links for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)
[Handling Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/handling_universal_links)

> 警告
> ユニバーサルリンクはアプリに潜在的な攻撃経路を提供するため、すべてのURLパラメータを検証し、不正なURLを破棄するようにしてください。さらに、利用可能なアクションを、ユーザーのデータを危険にさらさないものに制限します。たとえば、ユニバーサルリンクがコンテンツを直接削除したり、ユーザーに関する機密情報にアクセスしたりすることを許可しないでください。URL処理コードをテストするときは、テストケースに不適切な形式のURLが含まれていることを確認してください。

[Wi-Fi QRコードを作成してアクセスポイントに接続してみた](http://gravedoll.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/13/234838)
[家族のスマホWi-Fi接続を簡単に済ませるとっておきテク](https://internet.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/column/homewifi/1125514.html)

[QR Code WIFI How to create QR Code to WIFI.](https://qrcodego.com/pages/qr-code-wifi/)
[QR Code link How to create QR Code to link.](https://qrcodego.com/pages/qr-code-link/)

[【FAQ】QRコードを読むだけでWi-Fiに接続できる方法があると聞いたのですが！](https://andronavi.com/2017/02/380059/)

> おすすめのアプリは『QR Droid』や『  Wifi QR Code Generator』です。簡単にQRコード化できるのでぜひ使ってみてください。

[『QR Droid (日本語)』～読み込むだけじゃない！なんでもQRコードにできるアプリ～](https://andronavi.com/2012/06/196790/)
[QR Droid Code Scanner (日本語)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr)
[Wifi QR Code Generator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madeng.wifiqr)

[QRコードの仕組みとは？各分野で広がるQRコードの活用方法](https://orange-operation.jp/posrejihikaku/business-app/11326.html)
[GoogleのQRコードログインのしくみを勝手に想像する](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ritou/20120117/1326808401)
[QRコードログイン機能を悪用したLINEアカウント乗っ取りの危険性とその成功可能性・ユーザー像について](https://did2memo.net/2016/06/02/naver-line-qr-code-login-security/)

---

**別の情報**
質問者さんの求める仕組みとは違うのですが、機器やサービス側でやっている場合もあるようです。WiFiに接続すると、さらにサービスへのログイン画面が表示される場合などが該当すると思われます。

[ゲストに指定したサイトを表示する（URLリダイレクト）](http://www.aterm.jp/function/wg2600hp2/guide/url_redirect.html)

> 本機能をご利用になると、本商品のゲストSSIDでインターネットにアクセスしたパソコンやスマートフォン／タブレット端末 に、最初に、あらかじめ指定したサイトを表示することができます。

[無線LAN接続時、又はブラウザ起動時に特定のWEBサイトを自動的に表示させる。](http://popchat.jp/2013/08/07/qa20130306/)

> POPCHAT機はブラウザによる認証を行った後に、指定のWEBサイトを表示させる機能がございます。

[指定Webサイト表示 - ギガらくWi-Fi サービス詳細・仕様](https://business.ntt-east.co.jp/service/gigarakuwifi/service.html)

> 来訪者がWi-Fiを利用してインターネットに接続する際に、任意のWebページを表示します。

[インターネット接続中にTOKYO FREE Wi-Fiのサイトが勝手に表示されます。 - TOKYO FREE Wi-Fi](http://www.wifi-tokyo.jp/ja/faq.html)

> 端末のWi-Fi設定をONにしている場合、端末が電波を感知すると、自動的にWi-Fiポータルサイトが表示されます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。タイトルを変更いたしました。質問内容を気をつけます。

Comment: 店舗などのでQRコードで Free Wi-Fi の SSIDに接続すると特定ページが表示されるものを実現したいということでしたら、これらはこちらの回答の後半にあるリダイレクト機能を使っていると思われます。